# How to access the "foo" controller in the jhipster-sample-app?

Tags: jhipster

I'm starting to learn AngularJS and as Java/Maven/Spring developer, the jhipster yeoman generator looks great.

I've cloned the jhipster-sample-app, imported it into my IDE and started it via Maven command `mvn spring-boot:run`.  (I know that when I want to generate my own app, i can use `yo jhipster`)

I am able to browse the app at `http://localhost:8080/` and also login as 'user' and 'admin'

**How do I navigate to the Foo entity in the sample app?**

I've tried `http://localhost:8080/#/foo` which redirects back to the homepage.

On the server side, I see the sample app has a Foo entity, repository, and resource.  On the AngularJS side, I also there is a Foo controller, router, service, and view.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample is just an example of the "default" application, the "foo" entity is not complete.

If you use the generator, here are the steps to make the "foo" entity working:
http://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_entity.html

There are basically the same steps to do on the sample application: you need to set up the database tables (in Liquibase, they are just commented), and import the JS files in your main app.

But you are right, we should generate a complete entity in the sample application (or no entity at all!), but not provide this half complete result.